# React - Can't find serviceWorker.js file in app src folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new about react and I am following different tutorials trying to understand fundamentals. I'm using the v17 of react.

In those tutorials, I saw a file in the folder structure named serviceWorker.js that is used for making a progressive web app.

I generated my project with npx but in my folder structure, I can't find this file. Is it a bug? or is it something deprecated? or do I have to add it manually?

Comment: If you've used `npx create-react-app`, it should be present in the `src/` folder. Can you maybe add a screenshot of your directory structure?

Comment: @CerebralFart the file is no longer generated since version 4. it is now called reportWebVitals

Comment: @azium, I didn't know that, thanks for the correction!

Comment: also you can create new project from cra template `npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa`, you'll get this file

Comment: Thank you for the answers!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, I expected to find this in my index.js:

```
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I looked again at my index.js to see what create-react-app had configured and found:

```
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
reportWebVitals();
```

This has replace serviceWorker in version 4 of CRA October 2020.

Answer (score 1):

From CRA 4 you can either opt in by using `cra-template-pwa` or by creating your own `src/service-worker.js` file.

But seems you only need to do so if you want to opt-in for the offline/cache-first behavior. The rest of PWA of tools are included in CRA.

It is all explained in https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was by creating the project like this:

```
$npx create-react-app name-pwa --template cra-template-pwa
```

and in the file structure you will find the file service-worker.js and serviceWorkerRegistration.js

and now in your index.js just change unregister by register:

```
serviceWorkerRegistration.register();
```